# Copying a worksheet into another workbook while changing its name

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a workbook which has all the administrative details for a language course. It has several worksheets:

1- course data
2- student data
3- course administration reports
4- student results reports
5- student marks data

The teachers can only have access to the last worksheet: they receive a workbook with that single worksheet which has a summary of their students and course's details, and they input the students' marks throughout the course. At the end, I import those marks back into the original workbook.

I managed to successfully use vba to do the above (and give the workbook a specific name) so that the teachers can have it in their power. (see below an excerpt)

```
Sheets("NotasProfSem").Select
    Dim filePath As String
        Calculate
    filePath = Range("AP2").Value & Range("AP3").Value & ".xlsx
    Sheets("NotasProfSem").Copy
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=filePath, _
        FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    ActiveWindow.Close
```

But the student & course information is still linked to the original file. So I devised a work-around: copy worksheet *NotasProfSem* into the same workbook as *NotasProfSem2*, turn the links into values, and then copy *NotasProfSem2* into a new workbook. But I need to revert the name of the worksheet to its original *NotasProfSem*.

**Question:** How can I make the vba code change the name of the worksheet when I copy it into a brand new workbook?

**Offering alternative solutions:** I'd also be interested in an alternative that allows me to perform "copy" > "paste value" of a group of cells while copying the worksheet into a new workbook. (If it is possible and easy - I am just getting my toes wet on vba).

NOTE: If my question and explanations are not clear, please help me improve them.

Comment: When targeting the new workbook, Activesheet.Name="NotasProfSem"

Comment: *So I devised a work-around: copy worksheet NotasProfSem into the same workbook as NotasProfSem2* ...  This is not necessary. Copy `NotasProfSem` to a new workbook, then flatten the formulas (links) on that worksheet directly. (`UsedRange.Value = UsedRange.Value` may work)

Comment: @Cyril - Thanks for your suggestion. It will come in handy in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do your trick:

```
Sheets("NotasProfSem").Copy

Dim wbProf as Workbook
Set wbProf = ActiveWorkbook

'remove links and formulas
With wbProf
     'this may not work as is depending on data structure, if not you may need to be more explicit with ranges / cells
    .Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value = wbProf.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Value
    .SaveAs Filename:=filePath, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close False
 End
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, you are right: I do need to specify the range. I've tried: **.Sheets(1).UsedRange("A1:M1330").Value**, but it doesn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: `.Sheets(1).Range("A1:M1330").Value`. If that does not work, check for the existence of merged cells and such. If they are there, remove them. If you can't you'll have to work around them when setting values.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks.